# What type of tyres I should use in UK?

Tags: winter

I recently moved to UK from Germany, and I was used to sessional tyres back home. Summer for summers season and winter for winter season. Now I live in south of the UK and I was told that I'm not legally obligated to change tyres in winter becoause there is no snow.

Should I invest into better summer tyres and use all year long? Or buy all-season ones? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are a variety of weather conditions in the UK, it would be a good investment to get all-season tires. It may not snow much, but it gets a fair amount of rain. Wet cold roads can be treacherous too, so better to be prepared.

All-season tires will provide good traction in a multitude of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people just leave their summer tyres on all year - we don't tend to get enough inclement weather for it to make a huge difference. I prefer all-season tyres though.

You can still swap to winter tyres if you want - this has been becoming more popular over the last few years. Check with your insurance company first though, as apparently some have been getting upset about people fitting differently-rated tyres to their cars...

Comment: http://www.theaa.com/motoring_advice/safety/winter-tyres-in-the-uk.html <- you may want to add this link.  Its odd that you will get charged more in some cases for making your car safer on the road.